# Remove Element (LeetCode #27): Difference in Speed and Memory

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, memory, runtime

I have came up with the following solution:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        k = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)-1, -1, -1):
            if nums[i] == val:
                k += 1
                nums[i] = nums[len(nums) - k]
                
        return len(nums) - k
```

which put me in 73rd percentile in terms of speed and 97th percentile in terms of memory. If I make a slight change to this code and started subtracting from a maximum number of matches (instead of counting them directly):

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        k = len(nums)
        for i in range(len(nums)-1, -1, -1):
            if nums[i] == val:
                k -= 1
                nums[i] = nums[k]
                
        return k
```

the runtime drops to 43rd percentile and memory to 53rd. Intuitively, the number of operations should not change so I struggle to understand what causes this change.